# Find total combinations of length 3 such that sum is divisible by a given number and i<j<k

Tags: python, algorithm

So, I have been trying to find optimum solution for the question, but I can not find a solution which is less than o(n<sup>3</sup>).

The problem statemnt is :-
find total number of triplet in an array such that sum of a[i],a[j],a[k] is divisible by a given number d and i<j<k.

I have tried a multiple solutions but the solutions all reached o(n<sup>3</sup>). I need a solution that could be less than o(n<sup>3</sup>)

Comment: if this can help: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/280743/find-all-combinations-of-length-3-whose-sum-is-divisible-by-a-given-number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let A be an array of numbers of length N:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Let D be the divider

```
D = 4
```

It is possible to reduce complexity O(N^2) with an extra dictionary that saves you iterating through the array for each pair (a[i],a[j]).
The helper dictionary will be built before iterating through the pairs (i,j) with the count of A[k] % D = X.
So for any pair A[i], A[j] you can tell how many matching A[k] exist by fetching from a dictionary rather than a loop.

Below is a python implementation that demonstrates the solution

```
T = 0 # Total possibilities
H = {} # counts all possible (A[k])%D = Key from index k

for k in range(2, len(A)):
  key = A[k]%D
  H[key] = H.get(key,0) + 1

for j in range(1, len(A)):
  if j >= 2:
    H[A[j]%D] -= 1 # when j increments it reduces options for A[k]
  for i in range(j):
    matching_val = (D - (A[i]+A[j]) % D ) % D
    to_add = H.get(matching_val, 0)
    T += to_add

print(T)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The key here is to think about the modulus operator. Each number `n` in the list can be expressed as `n = (x*d) + y`, where `y = n % d`.
2. For any 3 integers `x, y, z`, `(x + y + z)` will be divisible by `d` if and only if `(x%d + y%d + z%d) % d = 0`.
3. You can bucket all numbers in the list based their remainder (ie. `n%d`)
4. You will have `d` buckets (ranging from `0` to `d-1`).
5. Generate all possible triplets using integers in range `[0, d-1]` that add up to `0, d or 2*d`. This will give you the bucket combinations that can be used to obtain a valid triplet.
6. Since you know the number of elements in each bucket, you can calculate the number of valid triplets. (for example, if `bucket 0` has `10` elements, the triplet `(0,0,0)` will have `10*9*8` corresponding triplets).

This algorithm should be enough to set you on track to complete the problem. Leaving out the implementation and other minor details for the reader.

Comment: The algorithm you provided was helpful but the problem I am facing is with the constraint i<j<k. I do not think the algorithm will work properly with the constraint i<j<k

Comment: @NehalBirla why do you think it won't work? Also, what do you think is the real relevance of this constraint?

Answer (score 0):

As I was unable to edit the problem description, I'm adding the problem with the constraints for better understanding the problem:

**Problem Description:**

Count the number of distinct triplets `(i, j, k)` such that 0 < i < j < k ≤ n and the sum `(a[i] + a[j] + a[k])` is divisible by `d`.

**Example:**

```
a = [3, 3, 4, 7, 8]
d = 5
```

The following triplets are divisible by d = 5. Following are the triplets whose sum is divisible by d(1-based indexing).

- indices (1, 2, 3), sum = 3 + 3 + 4 = 10
- indices (1, 3, 4), sum = 3 + 4 + 8 = 15
- indices (2, 3, 4), sum = 3 + 4 + 8 = 15

Since there is no other triplet divisible by `d = 5`, return `3`.

**Constraints:**

- 3 ≤ n ≤ 10<sup>3</sup> , where `n` is the length of the array, `a`.
- 1 ≤ a[i] ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>
- 2 ≤ d ≤ 10<sup>6</sup>, where `d` is the divisor.

**Implementation:**

- Brute Force

```cpp
int brute(vector<int>& nums, int d){
    int n = nums.size();
    sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
    int pairs = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
            for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++){
                if ((nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k]) % d == 0){
                    pairs++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

**Time Complexity:** O(n<sup>3</sup>), i.e in the worst case the loop will iterate for 10<sup>9</sup>

**Hashmap based on reminder**

```cpp
int solve(vector<int>& A, int d){
    vector<int> freq(d, 0);
    int n = A.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        A[i] %= d;
        freq[A[i]]++;
    }

    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < d; j++) {
            int k = (d - (i + j) % d) % d;
            if (k < j) continue;
            if (i == j && j == k) {
                cnt += freq[i] * (freq[i] - 1) * (freq[i] - 2) / 6;
            } else if (i == j) {
                cnt += freq[i] * (freq[i] - 1) / 2 * freq[k];
            } else if (j == k) {
                cnt += freq[i] * freq[j] * (freq[j] - 1) / 2;
            } else {
                cnt += freq[i] * freq[j] * freq[k];
            }
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

**Time Complexity**: O(n<sup>2</sup>), and in worst case the iteration will be 10<sup>12</sup>

**C++ Version** of the above code

```cpp
int solve(vector<int>& nums, int d){
    int n = sz(nums);
    unordered_map<int, int> counter;
    int pairs = 0;
    for (int k = 2; k < n; k++){
        int key = nums[k] % d;
        counter[key]++;
    }
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++){
        if (j >= 2){
            counter[nums[j]%d]--;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++){
            int match = (d - (nums[i] + nums[j]) % d) % d;
            pairs += counter.count(match) ? counter[match] : 0;
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}
```